# set anchor for a PictureMarkerSymbol in arcgis android sdk

Tags: android, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android

I am trying to create a `PictureMarkerSymbol`in arcgis android, however I found that the marker use the center of the drawable as the anchor point, is it possible to set the anchor?

---

update:

This is the drawable(with 40x56 in pixel):

[image]

This is  my code for adding marker:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_imp_esri);
    mapView.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"));
    Point p = new Point(-9664114.480484284,3962469.970217699); //Birmingham
    mapView.setResolution(mapView.getMinResolution());

    GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(mapView.getSpatialReference(), new Envelope(-180, -90, 180, 90));
    mapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

    //add marker
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_a_normal);
    PictureMarkerSymbol sym = new PictureMarkerSymbol(d);
    sym.setOffsetX(-convertToDp(d.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2);
    sym.setOffsetY(-convertToDp(d.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2);
    Graphic g = new Graphic(p, sym);
    graphicsLayer.addGraphic(g);
}



private int convertToDp(double input) {
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (input * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

But this is what I got:[image]:

The four screenshot are captured during zooming in the map.

Note, at the image 1, the marker event does not at the united states.

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the anchor point using the `MarkerSymbol.setOffsetX` and `MarkerSymbol.setOffsetY`.

```
  symbol1 = new PictureMarkerSymbol(image);
  symbol1.setOffsetX(8);
  symbol1.setOffsetY(8);
```

Comment: I update my post, can you spare some time to check it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, the sdk will use the center of the drawable as the anchor when draw the symbol, so in my case , I just set the offsetY to make it work:

```
 PictureMarkerSymbol sym = new PictureMarkerSymbol(d);
 //sym.setOffsetX(-convertToDp(d.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2); not necessary
 sym.setOffsetY(-convertToDp(d.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2);
```